# Proving relation between time periods in an elliptical orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

[image]

> Given is a planet moving around the sun in an elliptical orbit NMLO . I was trying to prove that the time T1 taken to cover distance NOL is greater than the time T2 taken to cover distance LMN.

*I tried to think of the fact that by conservation of energy , I am able to prove that the velocity of planet at each point in region NML will be greater than the velocity at the corresponding point in region LON. *

Is this the correct way to prove the time relations or is there a more mathematical or intuitive approach ?

Comment: Hint:  Kepler's 2nd law ("equal areas in equal times") which follows from conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: @BertBarrois how would area help when I am dealing with perimeters ?

Comment: You're not dealing with perimeters, you're dealing with radial vectors from the perimeter to the sun focus, S. Longer vector, slower tangential speed if angular momentum is constant: $|\ell| = |\vec{r}\times m\vec{v}| = mvr\sin\theta_{rv}$.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than thinking about the time taken to cover the distance NOL along the orbit, think about the time taken to sweep out the area from S along the NOL portion of the orbit. It's just a different way of expressing the same time period. And you know that the time period is proportional to the area, according to Kepler's second law. Do the same for the area swept out from S along the LMN portion of the orbit, and compare the two times.

You can calculate each of the areas swept out as being the area of half of the ellipse, plus or minus the area of a couple right triangles. And you won't wind up actually needing to know how to compute the area of half of an ellipse, because those terms will cancel out if you take the difference between the two areas swept out.

Comment: I can’t locate the right angled triangles

Comment: The right triangles are SNC and SLC, where C is the center of the ellipse.

Comment: And so I get the area differential and and using the rate of sweeping areas , I would be able to calculate the time differential , right ?

Comment: Right.${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Do you think my way of thinking mentioned in question is logically correct ?

Comment: Yes, using conservation of energy would also be a valid way to do it. There'd be a messy integration that way, but you could show that $T_1-T_2$ is positive without actually solving the integral expression for $T_1-T_2$, by just showing that the integrand is always positive.